# jQuery .on('change') function doesn't work on input[type=file]

Tags: jquery

I have something like that:

```
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){ 
console.log('changed!'); });
```

and it doesn't work. It works fine on other form elements, but not on input[type=file]. However when I change .on() function to .live() it works fine. I use jQuery 1.8.3 but I want to upgrade to 1.9.0 so there won't be .live() function anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"On" works fine with jquery 1.8.3.  You can try this code and check the demo below which works for me with jquery 1.8.3.

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(event){ 
     console.log('changed!'); 
});
```

Try this : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aZh47/)

Comment: And the same code worked for me when i changed to Jquery 1.9.0 on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I have theory:

Are you sure that your selector, **$('input[type=file]')**, is actually retrieving any elements? If you're dynamically inserting inputs into the DOM, it's quite possible that they don't exist when the selector is being run, and that would explain why **.live** works.

Try using this bit of code:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(event){
    console.log('Changed!');
});
```

If it works, you've found your problem... you're selecting elements before they exist and inserting them into the DOM after the code has run.

Comment: God bless you!!

Answer (score 0):

also you can try with

```
$('input:file').on('change', function(event){ 
     console.log('changed!'); 
});
```